# Refresh bottom navigation bar components

Tags: java, android

A bottom navigation bar with two fragments; Frag1 and Frag2,

The bottom navigation bar works perfectly switching between those fragments.

**The question is: Frag2 has a TextView with on Click listener; so once it's been clicked; it supposed that Frag2 should be vanished/disappeared while another new Third fragment (Frag3) would take its place**

Can you please help me answer this question because I have searched everywhere and no one has answered similar to this question

```
 final Fragment f1 = new Frag1();
 final Fragment f2 = new Frag2();


 private BottomNavigationViewEx.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener =
    new BottomNavigationViewEx.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {


            switch (item.getItemId()) {

               case R.id.Frag1:
                    fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(f1).commit();
                    active = f1;
                    return true;

                case R.id.Frag2:
                    fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(f2).commit();
                    active = f2;
                    return true;

            }


            return false;

        }
    };
```

Comment: Have you looked into using the new Navigation component from Jetpack? It can greatly simplify your navigation needs, you won't have to play around with the fragmentManager, transactions, etc. It is worth checking out, especially if you are just starting to learn android development.

Comment: would you please send me the link, Appreciate ur help

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started

Comment: Bro is there any other way to implement without using the new Navigation component from Jetpack, because I am using old version of Android Studio from some reasons, and that's won't work because the new Navigation component requires 3.3v of Android Studio

Comment: Can't you just initialize your third fragment and show it via a transaction on the fragmentManager when the clickListener on the textview is invoked?

Comment: I did as u said but the thing this doesn't work because u can see the condition in this code                                                                                                                    case R.id.Frag2:
                    fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(f2).commit();

Comment: Ah I see what you are trying to do. I guess if you want to keep the current structure of your code, you can set a boolean flag into SharedPreferences (say textClicked) to true when the textview is clicked, and in your switch case Frag2, check for that flag in shared preferences and load the correct fragment at that point.

Comment: Exactly that what i want, would you please show me an example code for my case